# Second Loop Only Inserting Character in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use pandas to convert a textfile with the following code...

```
AFNI_data_location = "C:\\Users\\jes6785\\Box\\Almeida_Lab\\BITREC\\BEHAVIORAL_FILES_CLEANED_JULY_2023\\"
BIDS_output_location = "C:\\Users\\jes6785\\Box\\Almeida_Lab\\BITREC\\BIDS\\"
condition=["circle", "emot", "neut", "square"] #should be listed in filename 
subj = os.listdir(AFNI_data_location) # this lists out all the files in the directory - for later

#Identify the folders in the directory, directories are already split by sessions
for subj in subj:
    print(subj)
    subj_only = subj.split("-")[0] 
    session = subj.split("-")[1]
    filedir = os.path.join(AFNI_data_location, subj)
    participant_time=pd.DataFrame(columns=['onset', 'duration', 'trial-type'])
    run="2"
    for condition in condition: # loops through each condition                        
        file = glob.glob(os.path.join(filedir, '*run' + run + '*' + condition + '*.txt'))
        for file in file:
            print(file)
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep = " ", header = None) 
            data = data.T
            data.columns = ["onset"]
            data.insert(1, "duration", run)
            data.insert(2, "trial-type", condition)
            participant_time= pd.concat([participant_time, data], ignore_index = True)
        participant_time=participant_time.sort_values('onset')
       
    participant_time.to_csv((os.path.join(BIDS_output_location,"sub-" + subj_only + "_ses-0" + session + "_task-cpt-" + run + "_events.tsv")), index=False, sep="\t")
```

The first time this loops through the list I get the expected output of (note I put this into table format so it's clearer to read)...

| onset | duration | trial-type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.308 | 2 | square |
| 10.758 | 2 | neut |
| 12.957 | 2 | square |
| 16.485 | 2 | emot |
| 18.947 | 2 | circle |
| 21.947 | 2 | neut |

The second time and for all further loops I get just 1 character of the third column which should be "condition"

| onset | duration | trial-type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.308 | 2 | s |
| 9.308 | 2 | q |
| 9.308 | 2 | u |
| 9.308 | 2 | a |
| 9.306 | 2 | r |
| 9.308 | 2 | e |

How do I fix this?  I don't understand what I am doing wrong as it works correctly for the first loop? The first time it loops, it treats "condition" as a string but the second time it splits the strings into single characters and doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Don't reuse the variable `for condition in condition:`. After this, `condition` will contain the last element of the list, not the full list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this issue due to using the variable name `condition` as both the loop variable and the list of conditions. It creates a conflict causing unexpected output. Change the inner `for` loop to:

```
for cond in conditions:  
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(filedir, '*run' + run + '*' + cond + '*.txt'))
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ", header=None)
            data = data.T
            data.columns = ["onset"]
            data.insert(1, "duration", run)
            data.insert(2, "trial-type", cond)  
            participant_time = pd.concat([participant_time, data], ignore_index=True)
        participant_time = participant_time.sort_values('onset')
```

Comment: Thanks to you both, I didn't realize it had to be named differently in this case.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining the variable `condition` the first time through the outer loop, because of

```
for condition in condition:
```

Use a different variable for the iteration variable than the list it's iterating over. E.g. rename the list to `conditions`, then use

```
for condition in conditions:
```